# How to use require_once to only load the variables from remote page, then prevent further execution of remote page?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, require-once

I am using `require_once` to load some variable values from another page, however, on the bottom of the 'remote' page is another `require_once` that loads the functions from yet another page.

I am trying to prevent the `require_once at` the bottom of the 'remote' page from getting executed. Is there any to stop the page from executing after I have retrieved the variable values that I need?

Comment: If it's just loading functions, what's the problem? Just don't call those functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I appreciate the suggestions, and I know they would work just fine. I am aware of the other options, however, I am searching for the solution to this problem exactly as stated.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file into a variable, remove the `require_once` line, and then call `eval()` to execute it.

```
$code = file_get_contents('otherpage.php');
$code = preg_replace('/require_once.*;/i', '', $code);
eval($code);
```